# How to put the static file in website root directory in python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have establish the flask project,And it can run successfully,but I want to put my images directory in my web root path,make the images  can be showed by visiting url http://mywebsite.com/images/test.jpg

I have tried to put the images dir under the static dir and under the  website dir and under the app dir,they are both no working.

I search google ,and put the images dir under static dir
try

```
@app.route('/images<path:path>')
def return_images(path):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path,'static/images'),path)
```

then visite http://mywebsite.com/images/test.jpg
it's no working..

I am a newer for python flask,so How to server static file in python flask?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014332/unable-to-load-images-on-web-pages-in-flask-web-application

Comment: the images path have been writen in front page,so I want to make images can be viewed by visite the url like [link](ttp://abc.com/images/test.png)

Comment: for performance reasons it's better if you let your web server directly deliver the images, so python doesn't have to deal with them too

Comment: @mauro.stettler yes,finally I server the images dir with nginx.just configure the location endpoint in nginx configuration file.thank you.